# Installing PyIpopt: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No

Tags: python, installation, ipopt

I'm trying to get Ipopt working with Python on Windows.
So far I've installed Ipopt (https://projects.coin-or.org/Ipopt) with CygWin64. This seems to work. Then I got the code from https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt.
I then used cmd with "python setup.py install" and I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\ansofi\Desktop\pyipopt>python setup.py install
C:/cygwin/home/ansofi/CoinIpopt\lib
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pyipoptcore' extension
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c 

/nologo   /Ox
/MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:/cy
gwin/home/ansofi/CoinIpopt\include/coin/ -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC
/Tcsrc/callback.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/callback.obj
callback.c
c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(
12) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DE
PRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
src/callback.c(37) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No
 such file or directory
error: command 'c:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\\VC\\BIN\\c
l.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Have the same question. Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: @dreamer Did you get solution for that???

Comment: @Nisar I don't think I did except for trying it on Linux; I'd recommend doing that in general because I think you'll run into more issues with ipopt otherwise when you try it through cygwin